# How to hide y axis line in ChartJs?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am using bubble chart and gotta hide the y axis line. I've tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
yAxes: [{
  angleLines: {
    display: false
  }
}]
```

Comment: Can you show the complete code you are using? Preferably In the fiddle.

Comment: Jaipradeesh, could you change the accepted answer, so the correct one is shown first?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

This disables the vertical Y axis line:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
        drawBorder: false,
      },
    }]
  },
},
```

This can be combined with `display` to disable the vertical gridLines:

```
xAxes: [{
  gridLines: {
    display: false,
  },
}],
```

Here's a working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqGGaV

Comment: Thanks! I also wanted to add that if you want to hide everything about the x-axis use ticks: {display: false}, gridLines: { display: false, drawBorder: false}}] for the xAxes key. The same works for yAses too of course

Comment: Kinda counterintuitive. I'd expect adding `display: false` to an object to hide everything there is..

Answer (score 39):

From version 3 upwards, you should use this options to hide axes completely:

Picture: [chartjs-without-axes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4yWJ.png)

```
scales: {
   x: {
      display: false,
   },
   y: {
      display: false,
   }
},
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to hide only the lines (and keep ticks) , move `display: false` config to "grid" parameter, like this:

```
scales: {
   y: {
      grid: {
         display: false
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this option will hide the ticks too

Comment: @RoyMargasa Thank you for pointing this out. I wrote a solution for hiding ticks problem

Comment: updated answer hides the grid lines but not the axis.  the below answer from @Developer works.

Answer (score 25):

**For Chartjs version 3.3.2 this works for me**

```
var barChart = new Chart(ctx,{
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales:
        {
            y: {
                grid: {
                    drawBorder: false, // <-- this removes y-axis line
                    lineWidth: 0.5,
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: correct answer for v3

Answer (score 15):

in version `4.1.1` I was actually looking for:

```js
scales: {
  y: {
    border: {
      display: false,
    },
}
```

Answer (score 12):

```
var myBubbleChart = new Chart(ctx,{
    type: 'bubble',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales:
        {
            yAxes: [{
                gridLines : {
                    display : false
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 11):

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

var data = {
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'First Dataset',
            data: [
                { x: 20, y: 30, r: 10 },
                { x: 40, y: 10, r: 10 },
                { x: 30, y: 20, r: 30 }
            ]
        }]
};

var myBubbleChart = new Chart(ctx,{
    type: 'bubble',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales:
        {
            yAxes: [{
                display: false
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That would hide the axes itself. I need the ticks. But not the line.

Answer (score 5):

so if you only want to hide the grid lines only on the chart , but keep the axis line:

```
gridLines : {
    drawOnChartArea: false
}
```

With above examples it will be like:

```
var myBubbleChart = new Chart(ctx,{
    type: 'bubble',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales:
        {
            yAxes: [{
                gridLines : {
                    drawOnChartArea: false
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked for me (2.9.4),  previous answers seem to be for older versions.

Comment: Perfect. Worked like a charm!!

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

```
scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        display: false,
    }],
    yAxes: [{
        display: false,
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your option config like this

```html
 options: {
        legend: {
        display: false
    },

        title: {
            display: true,
            text: title+` (${data.reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)})`
        }
        ,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                display: false,
                
            }]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the latest chart.js (v2.9.3) library:
You can do this in chart options to disable a particular axis:

[image: Disable A particular axis in the chart]

This chart can be obtained like so:

```js
  scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          gridLines: {
            display: false,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
```