# Removing axes lines on chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I have been working with some Chart.js and I have been trying to figure out how to remove the axis lines on a chart.

[You can see the grid lines I am trying to remove in this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw39y.png)

I have managed to remove the grid lines that appear within the chart where the data is represented, but I am having an issue removing these two lines.

You can see the chart.js I have created for the chart below.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("volCause").getContext('2d');
var volCause_Doughnut = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
            labels: <?php echo $cause_label_json?>,
        datasets: [{
            backgroundColor: benefactoGraph_colours,
            data: <?php echo $cause_value_json?>

        }]
    },

    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        legend: {
            display: false,
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Volunteer Hours',
                },
                gridLines: {
                    display: false,
                },
            }],

            yAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    display: false,

                }
            }]

        }

    }
});
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the **`drawBorder`** property of grid-lines to **`false`** in order to remove those axis lines, like so :

```
...
scales: {
   xAxes: [{
      scaleLabel: {
         display: true,
         labelString: 'Volunteer Hours',
      },
      gridLines: {
         display: false,
         drawBorder: false //<- set this
      },
   }],
   yAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
         display: false,
         drawBorder: false //<- set this
      }
   }]
}
...
```

Comment: As of v2.9.3, I don't believe `drawBorder: false` is needed. [My related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47328105/removing-axes-lines-on-chart-js/59720067#59720067)

Comment: For **version 3.3.2** this works for me. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593123/how-to-hide-y-axis-line-in-chartjs/68025610#68025610)

Answer (score 4):

You can set display: false in your axis object

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    display: false,
    gridLines: {}
  }],
  yAxes: [{
    display: false,
    gridLines: {}
  }]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct for different versions of chart.js, but as of Jan 2020, with version 2.9.3, I was able to resolve the issue by nesting `display: false` inside of `gridlines` as follows:

```
    ...
  , options:
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          gridLines: {
              display: false
          },
    ...
```

Here's a [related GitHub issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/6949).